# If three successive letters are chosen, what is the most likely sequence of vowels and consonants?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

An analysis of a text reveals that a vowel (v) is followed by a consonant (c) $75\%$ of the
time and a consonant is followed by a vowel $65\%$ of the time.

If three successive letters are chosen, what is the most likely sequence of vowels and consonants?

I constructed the transition matrix $A$ and calculated the proportion of consonants and vowels in the steady state. I found that the probability of getting a consonant is $\frac{15}{28}$.
But how to answer this question?

Comment: What is the probability of a vowel or consonant on the first letter?

Comment: The probability of getting a vowel in the first letter $= \frac{5}{26}$

Comment: There are only eight possible sequences: vvv, vvc, vcv, vcc, cvv, cvc, ccv, and ccc. So one way to answer the question is to work out all eight of these, and pick the most likely one. But I guess the only ones you really have to look at are vcv and cvc.

Comment: How can I compare the probabilities of them occuring?

Comment: @GerryMyerson And since the probability of a vowel on the first letter is $5/26$, then we get cvc as the most likely over vcv.

Comment: I think for the proportion of $c$ is $\frac{15}{28}$ in the  steady state and take into account that. How can the probability of the first consonant/ vowel affect this probability?

Comment: Why do you say the probability the 1st letter is a vowel is $5/26$? It doesn't say anywhere that the first letter is chosen uniformly at random from the whole alphabet. The point of a Markov chain is that the effect of the first item in the chain is wiped out in the long run. If you are correct aboout the steady state proportion of $c$ (and thus also of $v$) then you can work out the steady state probability of $ccc,ccv,cvc$ and so on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OP said that the first letter is chosen uniformly out of the alphabet in a previous comment.

Comment: @Rivers a deleted comment? I'm looking at three comments by OP, and I don't see any in which OP writes that the first letter is chosen uniformly at random.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "The probability of getting a vowel in the first letter $= \frac{5}{26}$" according to OP. That's the uniform distribution.

Comment: @Rivers, no kidding. That's exactly why I wrote, "Why do you say the probability the 1st letter is a vowel is 5/26? It doesn't say anywhere that the first letter is chosen uniformly at random from the whole alphabet." OP **never said** that the first letter was chosen uniformly at random; OP merely acted **as if** that was the case, without anywhere **writing** that that was the case, and I wanted to know **why**.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the Markov matrix $A$ for the eight triples
$$vvv, vvc, vcv, vcc, cvv, cvc, ccv, ccc$$
as they come in succession. You obtain
$$A=\left[\matrix{1/4& 0& 0& 0& 1/4& 0& 0& 0\cr
  3/4& 0& 0& 0& 3/4& 0& 0& 0\cr
  0& 13/20& 0& 0& 0& 13/20& 0& 0\cr
  0& 7/20& 0& 0& 0& 7/20& 0& 0\cr
  0& 0& 1/4& 0& 0& 0& 1/4& 0\cr
  0& 0& 3/4& 0& 0& 0& 3/4& 0\cr
  0& 0& 0& 13/20& 0& 0& 0& 13/20\cr
  0& 0& 0& 7/20& 0& 0& 0& 7/20\cr}\right]\ .$$
Solving $x=Ax$ gives
$$P(vvv, vvc, vcv, vcc, cvv, cvc, ccv, ccc)=\left({13\over448}, {39\over448}, {507\over2240}, {39\over320}, {39\over448}, {117\over448}, {39\over320}, {21\over320}\right)$$
$$=\bigl(0.0290179, 0.0870536, 0.226339, 0.121875, 0.0870536, 0.261161, \
0.121875, 0.065625\bigr)\ ,$$
so that $cvc$ has the highest probability $0.261161$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way using a smaller Markov Chain with 2 states of vowels and consonants: $$\begin{pmatrix}0.25&0.65\\0.75&0.35\end{pmatrix}$$ Its $1$-eigenvector is $(0.464, 0.536)$, so starting with this equilibrium state, the probabilities of getting $vvv$ is \begin{align*}P(vvv)&=P(v)P(v\to v)^3+P(c)P(c\to v)P(v\to v)^2\\
&=0.464\times0.25^3 + 0.536\times0.75\times0.25^2=0.029\\
P(vvc)&=0.464\times0.25^2\times0.75 + 0.536\times0.65\times0.25\times0.75=0.087\end{align*} where $P(c\to v)$ are the transition probabilities.

The other states can be worked out similarly, giving Christian Blatter's numbers.